# Combination Chakra Natures

Tags: naruto

What are all the chakra natures that can be used through combining two or more of the 5 basic chakra natures: fire, wind, lightning, earth, and water?

Comment: Go about a third of the way down this page. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in [here](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Nature_Transformation).

It shows multiple other nature chakras like ice and scorch.

Comment: This is a link only answer effectively, which is frowned upon.